# Service updating an activity that is not active

Tags: android, android-intent, service

What is the best way to accomplish this?

> 1) The MainActivity (i.e. the UI) is created and starts a service that starts listening to a TCP socket (should it be a IntentService, since the MainActivity is the only client?).
>
> 2) The service receives messagges and updates the UI when something comes (using a LocalBroadcastManager?).
>
> 3) The user closes the activity by clicking back or home button. The MainActivity is not active anymore, but the service should keep running in background, receiving messages and somehow communicating with the MainActivity (which is not there). I have no idea about this, something like runOnUiThread()?
>
> 4) When the user comes back and resumes the MainActivity, the UI should not only show the new messages, but also the "old" ones: every message it has received since the service started.
>
> 5) Messages are not permanent: they should be deleted if the entire app is killed, the phone turned off ecc. They have the same life-cycle of the service.

My fear is that there's no such a thing like communicating with an activity that is not active (point 3) and I should write messages in a local file, checking it for updates onCreate() and onResume(). Is there a smarter way? Points 3 and 4 are the critical ones. What is the best way to accomplish them? (no need to write code, just explain using keywords or link to examples).

Comment: You need to cache the messages in a database and you can use a sync adapter. Downlaod and check the Google I/O aap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The MainActivity is not active anymore

The `MainActivity` may be destroyed, more than merely "not active".

> and somehow communicating with the MainActivity

Even if there is an instance of `MainActivity` that is not yet garbage-collected, if it is destroyed, it will never be used again. And you cannot talk to a `MainActivity` instance that does not yet exist.

> When the user comes back and resumes the MainActivity, the UI should not only show the new messages, but also the "old" ones: every message it has received since the service started.

`MainActivity` needs to *pull* the data in this case, rather than having the data be pushed to it. Whether the pull is by asking the service for this data (via `bindService()`, via posting a `GimmeMyData` event on an event bus, etc.), or whether it is that the activity and service are working through some intermediary (e.g., `ContentProvider`), is up to you.